# Unable to login to NPM

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-package, npm-login

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNLK3.png)

I have been trying to create an package in NPM and tried to publish it. When I try to

```
npm login
```

I am facing this issue. I have no prozies, but It keeps on giving prozy error.

I have been trying to login npm. The error keeps me stuck.

```
npm notice Log in on https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/-/v1/login failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy-host
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```